# How to apply CSS changes for the last <p> element of the 3rd div class span8

Tags: html, css

I need to apply CSS changes for the last `<p>` element of the 3rd `<div class="span8">` without using jQuery.

HTML

```
<div class="span8">
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>This collection includes video, audio and essays.</p>
    <p class="last">Visit now</p>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div><br/>

<div class="span8">
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>This collection includes video, audio and essays.</p>
    <p class="last">Visit now</p>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div><br/>

<div class="span8">
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>This collection includes video, audio and essays.</p>
    <p class="last">Visit now</p>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div><br/>
```

CSS

```
div.span8>p:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    font-style: bold;  
}
```

OUTPUT

**Some text.**
This collection includes video, audio and essays.
**Visit now**
Something else

**Some text.**
This collection includes video, audio and essays.
**Visit now**
Something else

**Some text.**
`This collection includes video, audio and essays.`
**Visit now** (this one needs to be bold.)
Something else

Comment: There's more than a few issues with the posted HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a class to the 3rd `<div class="span8">` like this:

```
<div class="span8">
    ...
</div>

<div class="span8">
    ...
</div>

<div class="span8 boldClass">
    ...
</div>
```

and you CSS goes like this:

```
.boldClass > p:nth-child(3) {
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Jsfiddle **[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/vhmy1ybg/)**

**============== Update ================**

Or, on a second way of doing this, you could create this same thing like this:

```
.span8:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(3) {
    border:2px solid #ff0000;
    padding:10px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

But also need to remove all the `<br />` from your code. I don't know why but these breaks are breaking the code (get it?! :P) when using `.span8:nth-child(3) > p:nth-child(3)`

Although instead of using `<br />` you could add a margin-bottom to `.span8` and then remove it on the last div

```
.span8{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.span8:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Here's an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/vhmy1ybg/2/)**

Comment: am using angularjs accordion component in that accordion heading i design a div element like this. so only i give a sample part of div element. you know its auto generated html conversion from angular js component. how possible to change the class. without assign the different class for the 3rd div element please tell me.

Comment: @sandysuresh88 you should've comment this answer and not try to edit it in order to ask or request something related to it.What you're asking is not much different than this, just exchange the `border:2px solid #ff0000;` for `border:0;`

Comment: Thnks chunk. i already made the changes. its work fine. Am new to this so nly i ask question